# Opteron 1212 vs. Xeon 3050?

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit

Any major reason I should chose AMD over Intel here?

Comment: Since we're not mind readers, could you describe what "here" is?

Comment: Here is the option of the two chips. Meaning, in this here situation, given these two options. Well the application is part web, part data mining. There's unfortunately not much more I even know at the moment. On balance, performance, which is preferable? Is one more stable? I could care less about power consumption, given it's dedicated. Thanks.

Comment: @PoppySeeds - I realize that there was a choice between two chips, but in certain circumstances one may outperform the other. I was asking the OP to elaborate on the use of the server.

Comment: The server is being used for numerical processing, not anything to do with web or databases. So it's a pure CPU performance issue.

Comment: @ApplePielsGood, then why the webserver and internet tags?

Comment: I removed the surplus tags. ApplePielsGood - unless you want to look totaly clueless, please at least make sure the tags have SOME relation to your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope- can't think of a reason for a server to use an AMD chip.  Intel has AMD completely outclassed currently in the server chip market.

Comment: In massively parallel systems the new AMD Opteron 6000 series could be a better choice, as some models have 12 cores.

Comment: um I think you missed the announcement of the new 12 core chips from AMD. They're 95% as fast as Intel chips on a per-core basis; but when you've got 50% more cores...

Answer (score 0):

In almost every circumstance, power consumption aside, the 3050 will be the better performer.